# Mysql - Fetch records order by desc and in random order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of videos in my MySQL database. I want to first fetch the 3 reconds who has highest no of views and then want to do a random on those records. Let's for instance I want 3 records in random order and order by views. For example, the data is like this

```
| id       | video         |view
| -------- | --------------|
| 1        | video/1.mp4   | 10
| 2        | video/2.mp4   | 20
| 3        | video/3.mp4   | 30 
| 4.       | video/4.mp4   | 4
```

The output should be like this

```
  | id       | video         |view
  | -------- | --------------|
  | 2        | video/2.mp4   | 20
  | 3        | video/3.mp4   | 30
  | 1        | video/1.mp4   | 10
```

Or

```
  | id       | video         |view
  | -------- | --------------|
  | 1        | video/1.mp4   | 10
  | 3        | video/3.mp4   | 30
  | 2        | video/2.mp4   | 20
```

I have tried this But it's showing up based on no of views in descending order. Its not doing random

```
ORDER BY view DESC, rand()
```

Comment: I can understand random rows sorting. But I cannot understand random inter-row data swapping. Why the relation between `id` and another columns is altered???

Comment: Select the videos in a subquery and then randomize the order in the main one.

Comment: you can use like `SELECT count(view) as view FROM tablename where view>10 order by RAND(),id desc limit 3`

Comment: @Vel well I don't want to limit the view for any number as I have done the pagination. for example on first time it will show 3 records and then so on again and again.

Comment: @Akina Please ignore the id part. It was typo error during writing question

Comment: then remove the limit

Answer (score 3):

Run a query inside another.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 3
) AS topthree ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: @LSemi, 

This gives an errror called duplicate ID

Comment: That is not an error a SELECT query may get. Can you post the exact text of the query you use, and the message you get?